# checking multiple values at once

Tags: ruby, if-statement, nested

So, pondering the X/Y of it all, I guess the real question here is- how DO you store data for a logic puzzle like this one? (Scroll to the bottom for a link to the puzzle.) I have chosen this hash, where every piece of the puzzle gets its own key + 5 offsets which can be marked T, F or nil. I am using 9 for nil because I can add 9, and the logic I am using leans on simple math.

I need to check seven values, and if all of them are a certain way, I then go set some other values. This check runs three times- it cycles through the three positions where the set of four nines and three zeros can appear

Here's my hash- in actual use, it starts out all nines, 9 = null, 1 = true, 0 = false

```
 $l1 = {
  1 => [9,9,9,9,9],  2 => [9,9,9,9,9],  3 => [ , ,9, ,0],  4 => [ , , , ,0],  5 => [ , , , ,0],
  6 => [9,9,9,9,9],  7 => [9,9,9,9,9],  8 => [ , ,9, ,9],  9 => [ , ,9, ,0], 10 => [ , , , ,0],
 11 => [9,9,9,9,9], 12 => [9,9,9,9,9], 13 => [ , , , ,9], 14 => [ , ,9, ,9], 15 => [ , ,9, ,0],
 16 => [9,9,9,9,9], 17 => [9,9,9,9,9], 18 => [ , , , ,0], 19 => [ , , , ,9], 20 => [ , ,9, ,9],
 21 => [9,9,9,9,9], 22 => [9,9,9,9,9], 23 => [ , , , ,0], 24 => [ , , , ,0], 25 => [ , , , ,9]}
```

Shown here as an example, the three instances of the pattern we are checking for appear in the 3rd, 4th, and 5th columns. I have removed the other values so you can see it better.

The pattern itself should appear in the second column, [2,7,12,17,22].

Here's the first iteration of the check using &&:

```
if $l1[2][2] == 9 && $l1[7][2] == 9 && $l1[7][4] == 9 && $l1[12][4] == 9 && $l1[2][4] == 0 && $l1[17][4] == 0 && $l1[22][4] == 0
    $l1[7][0] = 0
    $l1[7][1] = 0
    $l1[7][3] = 0
end
```

I also tried it with seven nested if statements, and it just stops matching two or three steps in even though the pattern is a perfect match.

How else can you check something like this? Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: expanding the explanation- I have zero formal training in programming other than a few courses at codecademy. I am building logic to solve the "Whose Fish?" puzzle, http://www.coudal.com/thefish.php , and this puzzle goes something like this-

There are five men, from five countries, living in a row in five different colored houses, they smoke different brands, drink different drinks, and have different pets.

There are 15 clues and no way to solve this without a pencil and paper or a spreadsheet... my goal is to make logic which solves the puzzle withOUT making any intuitive leaps myself- they have to be coded into the program. Clues + logic either solve it, or I need to re-tune the logic.

I have a lot of the logic built already, but the specific logic for this special clue "the green house is on the left of the white house" is proving pretty difficult to build.

I didn't want to mire eveyone down in a very long story, but it looks unavoidable...

So yes, the data all being stored in one hash like this is possibly counter-intuitive, but it's all I could come up with for data storage that I could figure out how to easily dump out and view to debug, and it's easy to look at for me as a beginner, and I have already switched it from five separate hashes- one for each man- because I ran into problems understanding how to build the logic when there were five hashes. Thanks again for looking into this with me.

Comment: I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. This datastructure seems very unintuitive (why do you use a 9 instaed of a nil?) and complex (A hash of arrays of number that tell nothing). Can you please explain what problem you need to solve and not how you want to solve that?

Comment: +1 "Can you please explain what problem you need to solve and not how you want to solve that?" This seems like an [X/Y question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you ask about X but the problem really is Y.

Comment: @theTinMan OK, I have added details on the problem I need to solve- and yes, for sure my hash is an odd way to store my answers/processing, but the puzzle I am solving will definitely require a perturbing level of complexity somewhere in its workings. If you were to solve this puzzle by hand, a 5 x 5 grid of slots for five possible results is one obvious way to lay it out. This is the only path, so far, that gets me- very-new-to-programming- anywhere near building my own solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I do not know why it is working now, but I took my three nested passes and made them into their own methods, and it's working right.

Before it was like this:

```
 if X == 1
   if Y == 2
    if Z == 3
    Q = 0
    end
   end
 elsif X == 2
   if Y == 3
    if Z == 4
    Q = 1
    end
   end
  end
```

Now it's like this

```
def first
 if X == 1
   if Y == 2
    if Z == 3
    Q = 0
    end
   end
 end
end
 def second
  if X == 2
    if Y == 3
     if Z == 4
     Q = 1
     end
    end
   end
 end
```